# Prime number in set $\{1,...,60\}$

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, inclusion-exclusion

How can we calculate by using the principle of inclusions and exclusions how many prime numbers are in the set $ \{1, ..., 60 \} $?

Comment: Use the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ where $x$ is the largest element in the set. There is no other way of computing $\pi(x)$ other than counting although $\operatorname{Li}(x)$ is pretty good for larger $x$'s.

Comment: @Alizter That's kind of tautological. The mention of inclusion-exclusion suggests the expected strategy was sieve-based, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Observation: Any composite number between 2 and 60 has a prime factor less than $\sqrt{60}$. So any composite number in that range must be divisible by 2, 3, 5 or 7. What is the number of composites in this range then?

Comment: For a little bit extra help if you want see this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes